# How to upload file format .tar/.rar/.zip in .net core mvc using .net 6 c#

Tags: asp.net-core

I have below code:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" asp-for="MyFile" />

        <input type="submit"asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddData" />
    </form>
</div>
```

but it not work when upload file with format .tar/.rar/.zip

Comment: Show the controller code. And file upload implementation won't change based on file formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your controller code completely. I tested it here and it can be uploaded:

View:

```
@model  WebApplication192.Models.FileModel
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label asp-for="myfile"></label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input asp-for="myfile" type="file">
            <span asp-validation-for="myfile"></span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Controller（Simple test use）:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(FileModel file)
        {

            //Do something with the files here

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class FileModel
    {
        public IFormFile myfile { set; get; } = null;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it woking very good